# Structure of a thyristor

Tags: transistors, triac, scr

In the test of the thyristor ([BT151S-500L](https://datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/BT151S.html)) that I removed from the contactor driver (in the multimeter diode test phase), I saw that the gate-cathode voltage drop was 236mV, but the cathode-gate voltage drop was also 236mV. How can this happen?
I made the necessary connections in a circuit where the same thyristor and gate-cathode voltage were applied, it worked stably as it should, there were no problems.

This time I applied voltage between the cathode and gate, but the thyristor did not open as it should.

Although the thyristor was working, I suspected that it was defective and bought a new thyristor and tested it. When I measured it at the diode stage, there was no voltage drop between the cathode and gate as it should be, but later when I measured it at the Mohm (mega-ohm) stage of my multimeter, I saw a value of 16Mohm. What I don't understand is what the structure of the thyristor is. While transistor shows infinite resistance between emitter and base, thyristor does not.

[image: structure of a thyristor]

Comment: There is no standard for DMM operation in *diode* mode. The voltage should be high enough for a diode to conduct but lower than the breakdown voltage of most semiconductor bases or gates. If you have 2 DMMs, measure the voltage in diode mode with a second meter (open circuit).

Comment: I measured a small thyristor (SCR) with my Fluke DMM. It behaves as expected. Voltage drop is 0.7 from gate(+) to cathode. Open from cathode(+) to gate. Are you certain that one of your components isn't a triac?

Comment: Yes, the data sheet says it is scr. https://datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/BT151S.html